# Unit vector notation - both line and hat?

Tags: notation, vectors

I know that unit vectors are usually written in bold with a hat for example: $$\hat{\mathbf{i}}$$

But if you use vector notation with arrows (as I do when I write with pen and papper), should you both have an arrow above the vector and a hat, or just the hat?

Thanks!

Comment: You can write $$\frac{\vec{a}}{|\vec{a}|}$$ or $$\hat{i}$$

Comment: Thanks for the input! Yes, I know of that notation, but it feels a bit cumbersome. But maybe that is the best notation to avoid confusion

Comment: "Usually written with a hat..."  I think that is physics notation, not used much at all in mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, what indicates whether a vector is unit vector or not is the letter used rather than the hat ($\hat{}$). So, as long as you prevent confusion by not giving name $i,j,k,e_1,e_2$ etc. to some other vectors, $\vec{i}$ still is a unit vector. But I should also note that this also depends on the context in which you are using this notation. I don't know whether there is a context where $\hat{i}$ or $\vec{i}$ is a different vector from $[1\ 0\ 0]^T$ but I am sure that in some contexts, someone can name a vector $i$ even if it is not a unit vector (for instance where $e_1,e_2,e_3,$ etc. are used for unit vectors). But as long as you clarify your notation beforehand, I don't think there will be any problems when you use $\vec{i}, \vec{j}, \vec{k}$

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, the problem so like you stated not that often with i,j,k etc. Most often I have found that the position vector can be a bit difficult to interpret whether it is of unit lenght or not