# Should I use $\hat{i}$ or $\vec{i}$ when writing out a vector in full?

Tags: notation, vectors

There is another question related to vector notation here: [Unit vector notation - both line and hat?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3248422/unit-vector-notation-both-line-and-hat) but it does not answer my question. It questions using the arrow and bar together. My question has nothing got to do with that.

My textbook expresses vectors as:

$$\vec{v}_{(t=1)}=10\ \vec{i} + 21\ \vec{j}\ m\ s^{-1}$$

But my understanding is that the $i$ and $j$ are both unit vectors in this expression.

Would it be better to express the vector as:

$$\vec{v}_{(t=1)}=10\ \hat{i} + 21\ \hat{j}\ m\ s^{-1}$$

Obviously it's understood that the $i$ and $j$ are unit vectors in the first expression but I feel it's better to just use the correct notation.

Also the textbook labels the axis as $\vec{i}$ and $\vec{j}$. I have a problem with this as well as the axes are not vectors themselves. I think the axes should be labelled $i$ and $j$ without anything overhead.

Is there anything wrong with my preference of using $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{j}$ within the vector expression and $i$ and $j$ for my axes?

Comment: For print, there is also $\mathbf{i}$ and $\mathbf{j}$ in rather common use.

Comment: It is simply a matter of convention. Denoting unit vectors with a hat on them is sometimes encountered and there is no problem about it. Same for the notation of the axes. I should add that denoting the axes as the unit vectors is not a problem at all.

Comment: Notation is often not standard. My preference would be to use $e_1,e_2$ instead of $i,j$ or decorated varieties :-).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unit vector notation - both line and hat?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3248422/unit-vector-notation-both-line-and-hat)

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thanks but unfortunately no. It's a different issue related to the same notation symbols.